# Remove date from date-time axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot of value vs. time (not date_time) only.

Below is a sample code for reproducibility:

```
date_time <- date_time <- c("2014-06-01 9:30", "2014-06-01 13:15", "2014-06-08 19:0", "2014-06-15 0:15", "2014-06-29 3:0", "2014-07-20 16:15", "2014-07-27 20:30", "2014-08-03 14:15", "2014-08-10 1:0", "2014-08-24 20:30", "2014-08-31 1:15", "2014-08-31 10:30", "2014-08-31 11:15", "2014-08-31 17:45", "2014-09-07 13:45", "2014-09-07 21:0", "2014-09-07 21:30", "2014-09-14 14:30", "2014-09-14 16:30", "2014-09-14 21:30", "2014-09-21 14:0", "2014-09-21 19:15", "2014-09-28 10:45", "2014-09-28 20:0", "2014-10-05 8:15", "2014-10-05 9:30", "2014-10-05 23:45", "2014-10-12 1:0", "2014-10-12 2:45", "2014-10-12 11:45", "2014-10-12 18:0", "2014-10-19 19:45", "2014-10-19 21:15", "2014-10-26 12:45", "2014-10-26 14:30", "2014-10-26 17:15", "2014-11-02 11:30", "2014-11-02 15:0", "2014-11-09 12:15", "2014-11-09 18:0", "2014-11-16 19:15", "2014-11-16 21:45", "2014-11-23 16:30", "2014-11-23 18:30", "2014-11-30 2:45", "2014-11-30 16:30", "2014-12-07 14:0", "2014-12-07 16:15", "2014-12-07 18:15", "2014-12-14 16:45", "2014-12-14 18:15", "2014-12-21 19:0", "2014-12-21 19:45", "2014-12-21 20:15", "2014-12-21 22:45", "2014-12-28 10:30", "2014-12-28 15:0", "2014-12-28 16:30", "2014-12-28 17:45", "2014-12-28 20:30", "2014-12-28 21:0")

value <- c(62.820, 82.044, 64.656, 70.128, 90.432, 68.292, 61.344, 95.508, 58.572, 20.678, 54.396, 56.880, 90.252, .320, 46.951, 21.102, 50.508, 63.324, 64.626, 90.396, 51.414, 11.340, 84.168, 84.708, 51.444, 87.192, 45.756, .670, 66.960, 88.096, 11.613, 76.140, 91.342, 76.733, 69.696, 23.688, 92.279, 82.141, 52.576,  3.045, 82.080, .460, 64.188, 49.536, 45.360, 62.485, 69.120, 56.592, 16.200,  0.112, 64.484, 13.675,  1.616,  1.861, 62.853, .600, 82.348, 63.873,  1.668, 64.751, 47.664)

df <- data.frame(date_time, value)
```

The code I used:

```
ggplot(df, aes(date_time, value)) + 
                    geom_point() +
                    geom_smooth() +
                    geom_hline(data = df, 
                               aes(yintercept = mean(value))) +
                    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

I've tried to use one the following to eliminate the date from the labels:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels = date_format("%Y-%m"))
scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m"))
scale_x_datetime(format="%H:%M")
```

but they give me the following errors, respectively:

```
Error in format.default(x, format) : invalid 'trim' argument
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

Comment: In your example, `date_time` in `df` is a factor. Make it of type `POSIXct` and `scale_x_date*` should work: `df <- data.frame(date_time = as.POSIXct(date_time), value)`.

Comment: @lukeA Thanks for the reminder. I resorted to using abbreviated months + year instead. I couldn't fix it for time but I am still interested in doing it with time.

Moreover, I had a for loop that loops over several variables and saves a (faceted) plot for every graph. It breaks with an error "Error in prettyDate....range too small for 'min.n'"
Any idea why?

Comment: Because the range of x or y values is too small for the minimum number of tick marks (see `?pretty`)? Hard to say, maybe some subsets have only one value...